# ERROR 000732 from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

What is the problem since i have "test_script" folder  extant in C: but arcpy detects as a truncated one (i.e est_script) and signals error.

[image: test]

Comment: Could you please edit your post to contain the text of the error *as text* in the question? Not everyone has devices on which that image is legible (especially on a weekend), and, more importantly, others won't be able to search on the error text to find the solution.

Comment: As there are multiple other reasons 000732 seems to pop up for users, if you are trying to utilize user input file paths and concatenate string variables with them, this solution helped me after hours of searching here and elsewhere online: [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32064/getting-full-path-of-layer-selected-in-drop-down-box-for-arcgis-python-script-to](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32064/getting-full-path-of-layer-selected-in-drop-down-box-for-arcgis-python-script-to)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python is treating `\t` as tab so you are really doing `C{TAB}est` you need to escape with `\\` or use a raw string using `r` e.g `r'C:\test_script'`

Comment: Without the raw string denotation prefix, you are essentially employing the tab 'escape sequence' -- see this: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Answer (score 4):

Try entering your path as a *rawstring*, such as in this snippet:

```
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(r"C:\test_script\Fish.gdb", ...
```

Basically, just prepend an **r**.